# Reverted with reason string 'ERC20: insufficient allowance'

Tags: erc-20-approve, hardhat-deploy

I'm newbie on solidity and I'm trying a simple ERC20 on hardhat with task for understand use case

I follow this steps

- Mint in owner
- Owner owns N token
- Owner would to approve Receiver for receive amount of token
- When Approval Event is triggered it transfer from Owner to Receiver
  but ... 'ERC20: insufficient allowance' error occurs

this is my Token Contract

```
contract MyToken is Ownable, ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
    }
    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(account, amount);
    }

    function burn(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

This is my task

```
let signer = ... EOA // who deployed the Token contract
let receiver = ... EOA // other account
const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer)
const TOTAL_SUPPLY = 1000000000001;
await contract.mint(signer.address, TOTAL_SUPPLY);

contract.on("Approval", async (sender, approved, amount) => {
    console.log("sender = " + sender + "; approved = " + approved + "; tokenId = " + amount)
    const trans = await contract.transferFrom(sender, approved, amount) // 'ERC20: insufficient allowance' error occurs
    await trans.wait(1)
});

const trans = await contract.approve(receiver.address, 333)
await trans.wait(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try change the following line:

```
const trans = await contract.approve(receiver.address, 333)
```

to:

```
const trans = await contract.approve(signer.address, 333)
```

If it works, which most probably should, you have to use `transferFrom` method only when you want to transfer the tokens indirectly eg. from some others smart contract method. In your case since the transaction origin is your `signer.address` you can just make `transfer(...)`

Comment: Signer  has to approve hisself for transferFrom if signer is already owns your token ? I don't understand that use case